# Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Temple OS

Tags: fedora, drivers, virtualbox

Hi I have ran into this issue with using Fedora. Would love it if I could get some help.

[image]

So how do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. What you need to do is those commands in the terminal:

```
sudo dnf install kernel-devel kernel-headers dkms qt5-qtx11extras  elfutils-libelf-devel zlib-devel
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```